# How to program USB RFID reader/writer module?

Tags: c, rfid, c++

I bought an USB RFID reader/writer module from local store, it is not well known and branded, It connect to computer with USB port , and i want to write a program for it in Linux Ubuntu.

I find out (from CD with module) it use:

```
Silicon Laboratories CP210x USB to RS232 serial adaptor
```

I install the Driver from CD on Ubuntu and i compiled and run the example C++ file is in [this](https://github.com/GBert/CP2104_GPIO/blob/master/cp210x_gpio_example.c) link.

Now i want to send charachter message to it and receive proper massage from it but the example just send HEX value and if i put char in ioctl, it wont work, i tried this:

```
static const char HELLO3[] = "Howdy";
ret_val = ioctl(fd, HELLO3, &gpio);
cout << ret_val ;
```

It(ioctl) only get `long unsigned int`, I guess this integers should be in library but i don't know how to use them. How can i send massage to device and receive massage like response from it ?

The datasheet is not in English but it have some example for c# it is like :

```
serialport.writeline("W0abcdef65\r\n");
```

It mean write `abcdef65` on Block 0 and it receive ‫‪`Msg0000001‬‬` which means the command run perfectly. How can i get same functionality in C or C++ in Linux.

PS :

1-The library or driver is in the same folder as example link in github which i mentioned before.

2-The device works properly with the application carried with its package in Windows but i want to program it in Linux with C++ or C.

Comment: The C# example looks like it's accessing it as a serial port which makes sense because it's based on a USB to RS232 serial  adapter. Rather than `ioctl` you probably should have a /dev/ttyUSBn port you could open with a terminal program for testing or access something like this: https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html

Comment: @PeterJ thank you sir, the reference you mentioned is rather long, i'm going to read it and see whether it solve my issue.

Comment: Definitely not on topic for EE.

Answer (score 1):

Read the readme files for the headers on Github `Readme.Serial`.

> Although the interface connects to the serial port, it doesn't utilise
>   the RS-232 serial protocol and instead I/O is performed with bit banging.
>   Data output bits are sent through the DTR line and clocked on the falling
>   edge of RTS.
>   The Tx line is utilised to enable the application of the high programming
>   voltage on !MCLR/VPP and not for sending data bits.
>   Data input bits are read from the CTS line using the same clock as for
>   output with the data output line taken high for correct circuit operation.

I guess you will have find another way.